# IntelliJ flow analysis showing up in documentation

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to disable IntelliJs flow analysis from showing up in the documentation?

[image]

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4
Build #IU-163.12024.16, built on January 31, 2017

Comment: Could you please share your JSDK configuration, what jars are added to Annotations? Can't reproduce the problem on your screenshot.

Comment: @CrazyCoder using oracle jdk8 and the only annotation included comes from intellij/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar

Comment: Thanks, still not reproducible with the same configuration, we don't know what causes this behavior. Please [file a bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) with a sample project and IDE settings (File | Export Settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a bug report at
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169520
in case someone else finds this problem.